# Creating Dictionary by Consecutive Word Length

Tags: python

How does one create a dictionary from a sentence such that the keys-values only include consecutive words with the condition that the 'key' words are of length (`x`) and 'value' words are of length (`x+1`)? The function should only consider words within the sentence before any end punctuation (period, question mark, colon, exclamation point).

For example, a key-value pair from the below sentence would be

```
{'best' : ('bballs', 'coach')}.
```

Example Sentence:

> "The best bballs team is the NYCC State Warriors since they have the A+++ players and best coach and they should win most games this break."

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Does it work? If not what does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the words from the string using `split()`. Then iterate over these words and check if the length of the consecutive words match the requirements. To store the result in dictionary with multiple values for a single key, you can use `collections.defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

s = "The best balls team is the NYCC State Warriors since they have the A+++ players and best coach and they should win most games this break."
result = defaultdict(list)

words = s.rstrip('.').split()
for idx, word in enumerate(words[:-1]):
    if len(word)+1 == len(words[idx+1]):
        result[word].append(words[idx+1])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'NYCC': ['State'],
             'The': ['best'],
             'and': ['best', 'they'],
             'best': ['balls', 'coach'],
             'is': ['the'],
             'most': ['games'],
             'the': ['NYCC', 'A+++'],
             'this': ['break'],
             'win': ['most']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with regular expressions.

```
import re

sentence = 'The best balls team is the NYCC State Warriors since they have the A+++ players and best coach and they should win most games this break.'

result = {}
words = set(re.findall(r'([^ .,!?;]+)', sentence))
for word in words:
    re_consec = r'{}\s+([^ .,!?;]{})[^\w]'.format(re.escape(word), '{' + str(len(word) + 1) + '}')
    matches = re.findall(re_consec, sentence)
    if matches:
        result[word] = matches
```

This gives the next `result`:

```
{'NYCC': ['State'],
 'The': ['best'],
 'and': ['best', 'they'],
 'best': ['balls', 'coach'],
 'is': ['the'],
 'most': ['games'],
 'the': ['NYCC', 'A+++'],
 'this': ['break'],
 'win': ['most']}
```